# Adding ajax load more button to my front page

Tags: php, html, ajax, wordpress, pagination

I'm using a pre made wordpress theme for my site.  However, I wanted to make a custom front-page.php so I did, but now the problem is that I can't figure out how to add the ajax load more button to it.  My theme already utilizes the ajax load more button, so I thought it would be simple to add.  But I think I may be adding in the code at the wrong spot, or have my queries messed up?

Can anyone help me add this load more button?

my custom front-page.php

```
<?php 

    get_header(); 
    get_template_part ('inc/carousel'); 

    $the_query = new WP_Query( [ 
        'posts_per_page' => 13, 
        'paged' => get_query_var('paged', 1) 
    ] ); 

    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { ?> 
        <div id="ajax"> 
        <?php 
            $i = 0; 
            $j = 0; 
            while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { 
                $the_query->the_post(); 

                if ( $i % 5 === 0 ) { // Large post: on the first iteration and every 7th post after... ?> 
                    <div class="row"> 
                        <article <?php post_class( 'col-sm-12 col-md-12' ); ?>> 
                            <div class="large-front-container"> 
                                <?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array('class' => 'large-front-thumbnail')); ?> 
                            </div> 
                            <div class="front-page-date"><?php echo str_replace('mins', 'minutes', human_time_diff( get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp') ) . ' ago'); ?></div>
                            <h2><a class="front-page-post-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2> 
                            <p class="front-page-post-excerpt"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p> 
                            <div class="front-page-post-info"> 
                                <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a> 
                                <?php get_template_part( 'front-shop-the-post' ); ?> 
                                <?php get_template_part( 'share-buttons' ); ?> 
                                <div class="front-comments"><?php comments_popup_link ('0', '1', '%', 'comment-count', 'none'); ?></div> 
                            </div> 
                        </article> 
                    </div> 
                <?php } else { // Small posts ?> 
                    <?php if($j % 2 === 0) echo '<div class="row">'; ?> 
                        <article <?php post_class( 'col-sm-6 col-md-6' ); ?>> 
                            <?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array('class' => 'medium-front-thumbnail')); ?> 
                            <div class="front-page-date"><?php echo human_time_diff( get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp') ) . ' ago'; ?></div>
                            <h2><a class="front-page-post-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2> 
                            <p class="front-page-post-excerpt"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p> 
                            <div class="front-page-post-info"> 
                                <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
                                <?php get_template_part( 'front-shop-the-post' ); ?>
                                <?php get_template_part( 'share-buttons' ); ?>
                                <div class="front-comments"><?php comments_popup_link ('0', '1', '%', 'comment-count', 'none'); ?></div> 
                            </div>
                        </article> 
                <?php $j++; if($j % 2 === 0) echo '</div>'; ?> 
        <?php 
        } 
        $i++; 
        }?> 
        </div> 
    <?php
    } 
    get_footer();
```

the post-nav.php code that I found inside my theme

```
<div class="row pagination-below"><div class="col-md-12">
    <?php 
    $pagination_type = novablog_getVariable('pagination_type') ? novablog_getVariable('pagination_type') : 'pagnum';
    if($pagination_type=='pagnum') :

        the_posts_pagination( array(
            'mid_size' => 3,
            'type' => 'list',
            'prev_text'          => theme_locals("prev"),
            'next_text'          => theme_locals("next")
        ) );
    endif;

    global $wp_query;
    if ( $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 && $pagination_type=='paglink' ) : ?>
        <div class="paglink">
            <span class="pull-left"><?php previous_posts_link(theme_locals("newer")) ?></span>       
            <span class="pull-right"><?php next_posts_link(theme_locals("older")) ?></span>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php
        if ( $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 && $pagination_type=='loadmore' or $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 && $pagination_type=='infinite' ) { 
            $all_num_pages = $wp_query -> max_num_pages;
            $next_page_url = novablog_next_page($all_num_pages);
    ?>
            <div class="ajax-pagination-container">
              <a href="<?php echo esc_url($next_page_url); ?>" id="ajax-load-more-posts-button"></a>
            </div>
    <?php } ?>
</div></div>
```

This is how the load more button appears on my local host
[image]

example of what I want my front page post layout to look like. 1 post on a row, 2 rows of 2 posts on a row, 1 post on a row, and so on.  Then after every 15 posts the load more button appears.
[image]

This is what chrome developer looks like when I inspect the load more button
[image]

Comment: if you do inspect element what comes up? any errors?

Comment: I don't get any errors.

Comment: user6738171 consider this https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/load-more-posts-ajax.html

Comment: can you post your jquery?

Comment: @vel Here is the link to the theme file - https://www.dropbox.com/s/yghxnsvnbv3nnrh/novablog.zip?dl=0

Comment: Need to see your js too

Comment: The js is in there.  All the code from the theme is included in that file.

Comment: i cannot see load more button in your theme. is it template?

Comment: I've added what chrome developer looks like when I inspect it, if that helps at all.

Comment: in my case wp-admin customisation affect in admin-ajax.php response, try to deactivate all your plugin and try or if you did any customisation for wp-admin design wise remove those and test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to the front-page.php

```
<?php

get_header();
get_template_part ('inc/carousel');

?>


<script>
    var now=2; // when click start in page 2

    jQuery(document).on('click', '#load_more_btn', function () {

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
            data: {
                action: 'my_load_more_function', // the name of the function in functions.php
                paged: now, // set the page to get the ajax request
                posts_per_page: 15  //number of post to get (use 1 for testing)
            },
            success: function (data) {

            if(data!=0){
                jQuery("#ajax").append(data);  // put the content into ajax container
                now=now+1; // add 1 to next page
            }else{
                jQuery("#load_more_btn").hide();
                jQuery("#content-load-more-btn").html("<h4>No more results</h4>");
            }
            },
            error: function (errorThrown) {
                alert(errorThrown); // only for debuggin
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<section id="ajax"><!-- i have to change div to section, maybe a extra div declare -->
<?php

$the_query = new WP_Query( [
    'posts_per_page' => 15, // i use 1 for testing
    'orderby'=>'title', // add order for prevent duplicity
    'order'=>'ASC',
    'paged' => get_query_var('paged', 1) //page number 1 on load
] );

if ($the_query->have_posts()) {

        $i = 0;
        $j = 0;
        while ($the_query->have_posts()) {
            $the_query->the_post();

            if ( $i % 5 === 0 ) { // Large post: on the first iteration and every 7th post after... ?>
                <div class="row">
                    <article <?php post_class( 'col-sm-12 col-md-12' ); ?>>
                        <div class="large-front-container">
                            <?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array('class' => 'large-front-thumbnail')); ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="front-page-date"><?php echo str_replace('mins', 'minutes', human_time_diff( get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp') ) . ' ago'); ?></div>
                        <h2><a class="front-page-post-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                        <p class="front-page-post-excerpt"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                        <div class="front-page-post-info">
                            <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
                            <?php get_template_part( 'front-shop-the-post' ); ?>
                            <?php get_template_part( 'share-buttons' ); ?>
                            <div class="front-comments"><?php comments_popup_link ('0', '1', '%', 'comment-count', 'none'); ?></div>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                </div>
            <?php } else { // Small posts ?>
                <?php if($j % 2 === 0){ echo '<div class="row">';} ?>
                <article <?php post_class( 'col-sm-6 col-md-6' ); ?>>
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array('class' => 'medium-front-thumbnail')); ?>
                    <div class="front-page-date"><?php echo human_time_diff( get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp') ) . ' ago'; ?></div>
                    <h2><a class="front-page-post-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                    <p class="front-page-post-excerpt"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                    <div class="front-page-post-info">
                        <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
                        <?php get_template_part( 'front-shop-the-post' ); ?>
                        <?php get_template_part( 'share-buttons' ); ?>
                        <div class="front-comments"><?php comments_popup_link ('0', '1', '%', 'comment-count', 'none'); ?></div>
                    </div>
                </article>
                <?php $j++; if($j % 2 === 0){ echo '</div>';}?>
                <?php
            }
            $i++;
        }?>
    <?php
}?>
</section>
<div id="content-load-more-btn">
<button id="load_more_btn">Load More</button> <!-- button out of ajax container for load content and button displayed at the bottom -->
</div>
<?php
get_footer();
```

And then in the functions.php add this code below:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_my_load_more_function', 'my_load_more_function');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_load_more_function', 'my_load_more_function');

function my_load_more_function() {

    $query = new WP_Query( [
        'posts_per_page' => $_POST["posts_per_page"],
        'orderby'=>'title',
        'order'=>'ASC',
        'paged' => get_query_var('paged', $_POST["paged"])
    ] );


    if ($query->have_posts()) {

        $i = 0;
        $j = 0;

        while ($query->have_posts()) {
                $query->the_post();

            if ( $i % 5 === 0 ) { // Large post: on the first iteration and every 7th post after... ?>
                <div class="row">
                    <article <?php post_class( 'col-sm-12 col-md-12' ); ?>>
                        <div class="large-front-container">
                            <?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array('class' => 'large-front-thumbnail')); ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="front-page-date"><?php echo str_replace('mins', 'minutes', human_time_diff( get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp') ) . ' ago'); ?></div>
                        <h2><a class="front-page-post-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                        <p class="front-page-post-excerpt"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                        <div class="front-page-post-info">
                            <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
                            <?php get_template_part( 'front-shop-the-post' ); ?>
                            <?php get_template_part( 'share-buttons' ); ?>
                            <div class="front-comments"><?php comments_popup_link ('0', '1', '%', 'comment-count', 'none'); ?></div>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                </div>
            <?php } else { // Small posts ?>
                <?php if($j % 2 === 0) echo '<div class="row">'; ?>
                <article <?php post_class( 'col-sm-6 col-md-6' ); ?>>
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array('class' => 'medium-front-thumbnail')); ?>
                    <div class="front-page-date"><?php echo human_time_diff( get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp') ) . ' ago'; ?></div>
                    <h2><a class="front-page-post-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                    <p class="front-page-post-excerpt"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                    <div class="front-page-post-info">
                        <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
                        <?php get_template_part( 'front-shop-the-post' ); ?>
                        <?php get_template_part( 'share-buttons' ); ?>
                        <div class="front-comments"><?php comments_popup_link ('0', '1', '%', 'comment-count', 'none'); ?></div>
                    </div>
                </article>
                <?php $j++; if($j % 2 === 0) echo '</div>'; ?>
                <?php
            }
            $i++;

        }
        wp_reset_query();
    }else{
        return 0;
    }

    exit;
}
```

I think your loop settings in front-page.php have issues to resolve, in the **posts-per-page** parameter, displays the **posts-per-page** + **1** results.

Let me know if this resolve your question.

Comment: The red mark is not the load more button.  I have attached a picture above of what the load more button looks like when I have the theme uploaded.  For my home page I want to use bootstrap and I want it to alternate between 1 post on a row and then 2 rows of 2 posts per row, and so on and then have a load more button after ever 15 posts. (I placed an example in my original question).  I have tried to build this by coding that front-page.php.  And I think I coded it right (maybe?), but I just don't know how to add the load more button from the theme into that custom from page.php file.

Comment: How would the second code look like with all the code?

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. This code is not working correctly.  It only loads two posts to begin with (1 per row).  And then every time you press the load more button it just loads one post?

Comment: Please read the comments in the code, shows only 1 because i had been trying for testing. Posts_per_page option limit the number of post and paged shows the page of that posts_per_page belongs. You have a bug in the front-page.php first load query, but the ajax call is working ok. Change all posts_per_page to 13 and now you fix the only one response showing. Let me know if you still need help.

Comment: So sorry I missed that.  Is there a way to fix the bug?  I'm still new at coding so I knew I probably messed something up.  I changed the post_per_page to 15 (because I want 15 posts per page).  It works great.  There are 15 posts that show up before the load more button.  However, only 1 post loads each time after you press the load more button.  Is there a way to get 15 posts to load each time after you press the button?  Thanks again for the help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: @user6738171 change posts_per_page from 1 to 15 on ajax jquery area in front-page.php, after the name of the wp function inside the data array and you get 15 after button clicked.

Comment: Thank you, it works great.  One last issue - Is there a way to make the load more button disappear if there are no more posts to load?

Comment: The code is updated with the "no more results" text when the worpdress query is empty... i modify the jquery ajax functions in the success event, and modify the function in functions.php adding return 0 if query in wordpress is empty. Try again and you will get the message "no more results" when query results is empty.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I noticed you have to press the load more button before the message "no more results" will appear.  Is there a way to just hide the button in the first place and just show the message "no more results" if there are no more posts to load?

Answer (score 1):

You should probably just use an appropriate plugin to provide the functionality you're stuggling with.

This https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/easy-load-more/ claims to do exactly what you're looking for with "minimal" theme changes.